# Необходима ли точка после даты перед началом главы

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, необходима ли точка после даты перед началом главы? Ставятся ли какие-либо знаки, если после даты еще указано место действия? Например, "Москва, 1967(.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Названия глав книги — это заголовки.
Из знаков конца предложения в заголовках употребляются знаки вопросительный, восклицательный и многоточие.

[Знаки препинания в конце предложения](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=20)

Вот возможные варианты:
**Москва, 1967**
Москва, 1967 год
Москва, 1967 г. (точка — от сокращения слова "год")

Вот первые названия глав романа Ю. Семенова "Семнадцать мгновений весны":
"Кто есть кто?"
12.2.1945 (18 часов 38 минут)
15.2.1945 (20 часов 30 минут)

P. S. *...если после даты еще указано место действия?*
Тогда так:
1967, Москва
1967 год, Москва
1967 г., Москва